# Allow nginx access only from IP address

Tags: nginx

I have a domain, e.g. www.domain.com which is registered on IP XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, where my site is running on port 80.
I was wondering if there is a way, to block user access www.domain.com , forcing users to use only the IP address to enter the site.

Is it possible to set something like this using nginx?

Anyway, I am using Ubuntu as server, and any configurations on OS to solve this will be appreciated too.

Thank you so much.

Update:

Thanks to @mettalic the configuration now looks like this configuration looks like this:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name _;
   return 403;

}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name XXXX;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "http://XXX";
    add_header x-frame-options "DENY" always;


location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
}

location / {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "http://XXXX";
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/dist;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
}
```

It is fully working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one host on this server on port 80. You can create nginx configuration file without `server name`. Just `listen XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:80;`.

UPD:

You could try add server which will be return error to all users who will try reach your site by domain:

```
server { 
    listen 80; 
    server_name _; 
    return 403; 
}
```

or redirect them to ip:

```
server { 
    listen 80; 
    server_name _; 
    return 301 http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX; 
}
```

Comment: Not working. Connecting to www.domain.com goes straight into the site.

Comment: @MassimoLavermicocca you could try add server which will be return error to all users who will try reach your site by domain: `server {
    listen      80;
    server_name _;
    return      403;
}` or redirect them to ip: `server {
    listen      80;
    server_name _;
    return 301 http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;
}`

Comment: @metallic Please edit your answer to include your comment. This will constitute absolutely correct answer IMO.

Comment: @metallic I am really sorry, but is not working. I edited the question sharing the nginx configuration. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I just figured out I had to put the section having server_name _; at the top. Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 0):

Set `server_name 192.168.19.24;` in your host's config block.
On Ubuntu, the default virtual host is in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`, but that may be different on other distributions.